# How to Get The Oldest And The Newest Record of Different Columns By Person - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get **the oldest previous balance** and **the newest actual balance** of each person in a table of transactions.

For example I got this:

```
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| dateTransaction | idPerson      | previousBalance | actualBalance |
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 01-11-2017      |      1        |       0         |    1000       |
| 02-11-2017      |      2        |       500       |    2000       |
| 03-11-2017      |      1        |       1000      |    1500       |
| 04-11-2017      |      2        |       2000      |    2500       |
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

So I need to get something like this:

```
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| idPerson      | previousBalance | actualBalance |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
|      1        |       0         |    1500       |
|      2        |       500       |    2500       |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

This is the script to create the table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction]
(
    [numberTransaction] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dateTransaction] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [idPerson] [decimal](20, 0) NOT NULL,
    [transactionAmount] [decimal](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [previousBalance] [decimal](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [actualBalance] [decimal](18, 3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([numberTransaction] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried so far??  SO is not a free coding service.  Post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can try to fix your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number() over()` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
    , row_number() over(partition by idPerson order by dateTransaction ASC) as is_oldest
    , row_number() over(partition by idPerson order by dateTransaction DESC) as is_newest
    FROM Transaction t
     ) d
WHERE ( is_oldest = 1 OR is_newest = 1 )
ORDER BY idPerson, dateTransaction ASC
```

In the `over clause` the `partition by` means numbers assigned by `row_number()` will be **PER idPerson**. Then the `order by` sets 1 at the oldest date (when sorted asending) or 1 at the newest (when sorted descending).